# Retrieving menu information from mmjmenu api to deliver to my website

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to working with api and have been searching for the little tiny piece of code that makes the following snippit possible, but I am having trouble finding it. I have been watching tutorials on jquery, ajax, json, and php but have not found exactly what I need. If someone could show me a simple example of how the request would be constructed from the opening tag of the file to the closing tag it would be very helpful. After I get the data returned I can figure out how to parse and style it for display.
The first piece of code is the example that someone else said they use but I tried it (with my own api key) and I seem to be missing something. The second code is the "Mmjmenu.php" file that I assume needs to be in the same directory as the first php file. Following the code is the error I get.
("my api key" is replacing my actual key)

```
<?php
require 'API/Mmjmenu.php';
$client = new Mmjmenu('my api key');

$menuItems      = $client->menuItems();
$menuItems      = json_decode($menuItems, true);

foreach($menuItems['menu_items'] as $item)
{
    echo $item['name'];
}
?>
```

**This is the "Mmjmenu.php" file (can be found on git hub):**

```
<?php


class Mmjmenu {
    private $domain = 'https://mmjmenu.com/api/v1';

    private $active_api_key;
    private $active_domain;

    private $username;
    private $password;

    public function __construct($api_key, $active_domain = null, $active_api_key = null) {
        $this->setActiveDomain($this->domain, $api_key);
    }

    public function setActiveDomain($active_domain, $active_api_key) {
        $this->active_domain = $active_domain;
        $this->active_api_key = $active_api_key;
        $this->username = $this->active_api_key;
        $this->password = 'x';
    }

    private function sendRequest($uri, $method = 'GET', $data = '') {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mmjmenu.com/api/v1" . $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json'
        ));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ':' . $this->password);

        $method = strtoupper($method);
        if($method == 'POST')
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        }
        else if ($method == 'PUT')
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        }
        else if($method != 'GET')
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

        $result = new StdClass();
        $result->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $result->code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $result->meta = curl_getinfo($ch);

        $curl_error = ($result->code > 0 ? null : curl_error($ch) . ' (' . curl_errno($ch) . ')');

        curl_close($ch);

        if ($curl_error) {
            //print('ERROR');
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /****************************************************
    ********************* MENU ITEMS ********************
    ****************************************************/

    public function menuItems() {
        $base_url = '/menu_items';
        $menuItems = $this->sendRequest($base_url);
        return $menuItems->response;
    }

    public function menuItem($id) {
        $base_url = "/menu_items/$id";
        $menuItem = $this->sendRequest($base_url);
        return $menuItem->response;
    }
}
?>
```

**This is the error I get when executing the first file:**
Fatal error: Class 'Mmjmenu' not found in /home/...(my directory).../mmtest.php on line 4

Comment: The clue is in your require line. If you've put Mmjmenu.php in the same directory as mmtest.php then you need to write `require 'Mmjmenu.php';`.

Comment: Thank you so very much! Worked like a charm. I am embarrassed to say that I have been searching for that simple answer for over 16 hours! THANK YOU! Now I'm off to parse and style. btw, if at all possible I would greatly appreciate if there was a good direction you could point me to regarding parsing of the data. Again, HOLY CRAP! THANK YOU!

Comment: Sorry, I see the previous comment is too vague. I want to put the items returned into a div so that I can place them on the page.

Comment: Is it printing the list of names at the moment? If that bit is working then you just need to add any HTML you want to the echo statement.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a lengthy php file echoing the html to construct the menu and attached a css file. I was having trouble echoing the raw data from either the json or the decoded json (the php array data I presume), so that I can see what is there so I have a better idea of what information is available for me to parse/manipulate. I I also need to write a few loops because I have a lengthy for each with nested ifs for each menu category of items. Very inefficient.

Comment: So just to update, I discovered the answer to my "...having trouble echoing the raw data from either the json or the decoded json (the php array data I presume)," question. Its simple.  Use the preserved tag <PRE> so it looks like this:  echo '<pre>';  print_r ($myArray);  echo '</pre>';